# Odd SVM output - Need explanation

Tags: machine-learning, python, svm, interpretation, scikit-learn

I built a linear SVM model. My data has 105 subjects and 115 features, which I ordered from least important to most important. I iterated through them to find the f1-score with all 115 features, then with the best 114 features, then with the best 113 features, etc...

Why are the f1-scores so unstable? And how is it possible to have a high(ish) f1-score with only 1 feature?

My code and output graph are below:

```
y = np.array(mimic_d['Recurrent_epis'])
x = np.array(mimic_d.drop(['Recurrent_epis'], 1))
rows, columns = x.shape

f1 = []
num_features = []

np.random.seed(123)

for i in range(columns):
    pred = x[:, i:115]
    num_features.append(pred.shape[1])
    pred_s = scale(pred)

    xs_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(pred_s,y,test_size=0.30)

    svclf = SVC(kernel='linear')  
    svclf.fit(xs_train, y_train) 

    y_pred = svclf.predict(x_test)
    classification_report(y_test,y_pred)

    p, r, f, _ = precision_recall_fscore_support(y_test, y_pred, 
                                                      average='weighted')

    f1.append(f)
```

[image: na]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check if the features are correlated. That could be a possible explanation. Do PCA on the dataset and set the n_components to a small number and see the explained variance. I assume it would be high.